# Camera plugin flutter web

Tags: flutter, camera, flutter-web

hello I would like to know if there is a camera plugin for flutter web in order to take a photo and store it in a temporary path to then upload it to firestorage

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood correctly and i hope you already tried these packages image_picker & image_picker_web

Check these resources, it seems pretty same to your scenario;

https://github.com/flutter/photobooth

https://medium.com/flutter/how-its-made-i-o-photo-booth-3b8355d35883

Reply back if this is helpful to sort out the problem or share with us how did you solved it.

Comment: Thanks that's exactly what I was looking for !

Comment: @Snowy Finally happy to see this answer helped to solve your issue. checkout this stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers It encourages more people like me to answer questions like this. simply i can post the link in comment section but stackoverflow allow users to comment if they have above 50 reputations. hahaha.....

Comment: @AravinthanSubramanian the above links you mentioned works but it shows video but what if I want to take a image from web cam?