# Flutter web how take photo via webcam

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to know how to take pictures via web cam (not gallery) for Flutter web? Or is there a package that can be used for that? I have tried `ImagePicker().getImage(source: ImageSource.camera)` but it still open the gallery and cant open the webcam.

Comment: hello, i hope this may help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/68553701/14466045
This link guides you how to upvote the referred answer https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers